# Serverless task in Snowflake

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am executing below statement for serverless task it's throwing an error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE_2(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE_3(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP);

create or replace task DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
as
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values (2_1,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values (2_2,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_3 values (3_1,SYSDATE());
END
$$
;
```

****Error Message:
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 0 : No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.****

But the same executing successfully if i use the warehouse in the TASK

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP);
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE_1(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP) ;

create or replace task DEMO_TASK
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
as
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE values (0_1,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE values (0_2,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_1 values (1_1,SYSDATE());
END
$$
;
```

Comment: Check please if your role has EXECUTE MANAGED TASK privilege. If not then grant it as ```grant EXECUTE MANAGED TASK on account to role <ROLE_NAME>;``` to the role that is used to create task, and try to create task again.

Comment: I am using Account Admin, Do i need to explictly grant this privilege ? @aek

Comment: Account Admin isn't a super-user role, so you will need to add grants to it.  You may also want to take a look at this page in the Snowflake docs for best practices on using accountadmin.  Using it for object ownership isn't advised.  

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations

Comment: The issue is during runtime(task could be successfully created ) and it fails when serverless task contains BEGIN END block. When trying to run EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with single insert or single insert only it works without any issue.

Comment: @AlexanderM Nitpick: `insert into TASK_TABLE values (0_1,SYSDATE());` should rather be `insert into TASK_TABLE values ('0_1',SYSDATE());` (missing apostrophes)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, looks like you forgot to add USE Warehouse for creation of task, as creation of task is not metadata based action , so please use "USE WAREHOUSE  " sql statement before you execute create task

```
create or replace task DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
as
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values (2_1,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values (2_2,SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_3 values (3_1,SYSDATE());
END
$$
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The case is reproducible and my hypothesis is a serverless task does play well with standalone Snowflake Scripting `BEGIN END` block.

Initial setup(tested using Snowsight UI):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE_2(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP);
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TASK_TABLE_3(TBL_NAME VARCHAR, LAST_INSERTED_DATE TIMESTAMP);

SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
-- 7.5.2
```

Task test:

```
EXECUTE TASK DEMO_TASK_2 ;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.task_history())
ORDER BY scheduled_time DESC;
```

---

Use case 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_2',SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_3 values ('3_1',SYSDATE());
END
$$;

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

Output:

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 2 at position 0 : No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

[image]

---

Use case 2

No EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, only Snowflake Scripting block

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_2',SYSDATE());
insert into TASK_TABLE_3 values ('3_1',SYSDATE());
END;

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

Output:

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 2 at position 0 : No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

---

Use case 3:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with BEGIN END block including only single statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
$$
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());
END;
$$;

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 0 : No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

---

Use case 4:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE no BEGIN END and single statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
$$
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());
$$;

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

Output:

> SUCCEEDED

---

Use case 5:

BEGIN END block with single statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
BEGIN
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());
END;

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

Output:

> Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 2 at position 0 : No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.

---

Use case 6:

Single statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DEMO_TASK_2
USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL'
SCHEDULE ='1 minutes'
AS
insert into TASK_TABLE_2 values ('2_1',SYSDATE());

-- Task DEMO_TASK_2 successfully created.
```

Output:

> SUCCEEDED

---

Outcome:

- Task creation - succeeded  in all 6 cases
- Task run - succeeded only in case 4,6 (no BEGIN END block)

It should be reported to Snowflake Support.